# How to set the proper date format while importing CSV data in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am importing CSV data using Data Step in SAS EG. in CSV, i have a date column. The date is coming as **'20 Feb 2019 12:25:27 GMT'**

Code :-

```
Data Test;
infile 'Test,csv';
informat Date_Column date26.;
format Date_Column datetime26.;
run;
```

On running this code, I am getting date as **01JAN1960:05:59:23**. I have tried different format, but sometimes i only get date and sometimes errors.

Any way to get the proper date as **20-02-2019 12:25:27**?

Comment: There is a similar question with the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010783/sas-taking-date-data-in-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-from-a-csv-file-in-a-date-format-in?rq=1

Comment: Tried but It is not giving time along with the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to handle the "GMT" with SAS. Ideally, if you need to deal with datetimes from different time zones, I would recommend to get datetimes in your CSV according to ISO8601 structure.

If GMT does not matter, you can use the "ANYDTDTM20." to read the column.

The format that you describe does not exist as such. SAS has many approaching formats, you can find them [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001263753.htm). Let's take "datetime20." for the example.

If your really need this specific format then you will have to deal will separate dates and times and format it "manually" in a text variable.

You can try this code:

```
data test;

/* input date and time in text format */
in = '20 Feb 2019 12:25:27 GMT';

/* text date converted into SAS datetime */
out = input(in,ANYDTDTM20.);
format out datetime20.;

/* if format really matters */
outdate = put(datepart(out),ddmmyyd10.);
outtime = put(out,tod9.);
/* outformatted will have your desired format but will be a char variable, not a datetime */
outformatted = put(outdate,$10.)||" "||put(outtime,$8.);
run;
```